# Is this a valid idea for proving $ S' \subset \text{Span(S)} \implies \text{Span(S')} \subset \text{Span(S)}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, alternative-proof

> If $S'$ is a finite subset of $  \text{Span}(S)$ then $\text{Span}(S') \subset  \text{Span}(S)$.

Let $\displaystyle \text{span}(S')= \left\{\sum_{1 \le k \le m} a'_k v'_k: a'_k \in F, v'_k \in S'\right\}$, and $\displaystyle \text{span}(S)= \left\{\sum_{1 \le i \le n} a_i v_i: a_i \in F, v_i \in S \right\}$.

Since $S' \subset  \text{Span}(S)$ then we can write every $v'_k \in S$ in the form

$$v'_k = \displaystyle \sum_{j \in \left\{1, \cdots, n \right\}}a_jv_j  $$

Multiplying by $a'_k$ and summing over $k$ we have:

$$ \displaystyle \sum_{1 \le k \le m} a'_kv'_k = \sum_{1 \le k \le m} \sum_{j \in \left\{1, \cdots, n \right\}}a'_ka_jv_j = \sum_{j \in \left\{1, \cdots, n \right\}}(\lambda a_j) v_j $$

Where $\lambda$ is the (scalar) sum of the $a'_k$. Any element in $\text{span}(S')$ can be written in the form of the left hand side by definition, and the right hand side is a subset of $\text{span}(S)$ hence $\text{Span}(S') \subset  \text{Span}(S)$.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Another way to do that is to remember that if $S'$ is a subset of a vector space $V$ then $Span(S')$ is the intersection of all subspaces of $V$ that contain $S'$, i.e this is the smallest subspace of $V$ (by inclusion) which contains $S'$. From this definition it is very clear that if $Span(S)$ is subspace which contains $S'$ then $Span(S')\subseteq Span(S)$.

Comment: @Mark Thanks. Very nice. I was just learning about defining partial order to prove similar theorems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That approach is correct, but there is no reason for you to write$$\sum_{j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}}\text{ instead of }\sum_{j=1}^n.$$And it is not correct to state that “the right hand side is a subset of $\operatorname{span}(S)$”; the right hand side is an *element* of $\operatorname{span}(S)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for editing the question. I was over thinking a bit when I was indexing the sum, but it's now all very clear.